# Path Function in Laravel for URL With ID and Slug

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have created the following method in an `News` model in a Laravel project:

```
  public function path() {
    return route('news.show', $this);
  }
```

Now, this works just fine and returns the following url structure:  `www.mydomain.com/news/{id}`

However, I would like to tweak it a bit.  I want my url structure to be like this: `www.mydomain.com/news/{id}/{slug}`

So, what I want to know is how do I have to modify the `path` function in order to return this url structure - i.e., the one with both the `id` and the `slug`?

Here is one solution that I tried:

```
// web.php
Route::get('news/{article}/{slug}', 'NewsController@show')->name('news.show');

// News.php
class News extends Model
{
  public function path() {
    return route('news.show', $this);
  }
}
```

I then fire up tinker and run that path function and get the following error:

```
Illuminate/Routing/Exceptions/UrlGenerationException with message 'Missing required parameters for [Route: news.show] [URI: news/{article}/{slug}].'
```

I have tried other variations -- but nothing seems to work.

Any idea how to tweak this so that it does work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// web.php
Route::get('news/{id}/{slug}', 'NewsController@show')->name('news.show');
```

You need to pass article id and slug

```
// News.php
class News extends Model
{
  public function path() {
    return route('news.show', ['id' => $this->id, 'slug' => $this->slug]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- that did it.  It was the need to create an array that I was missing (I had tried passing the id and slug also - just didn't show it in the question).  Again, thanks.